# why do i get the highest valued number in my array as my first element when i use bubble sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm sorting some simple numbers using bubble sort with javascript and jquarry. The problem is that the number with the highest value will be sorted as the first element in the array.

Enter some numbers that need to be sorted  :
    
    
     Sort

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {

        var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
        var arr = numbers.split(",");
        var temp;

        arr.forEach(function(e) {
          arr.forEach(function (a, b) {

            if (arr[a] > arr[b]) {
              temp = arr[a];
              arr[a] = arr[b];
              arr[b] = temp;

            }
          })
        })

        $("h1").text(arr.join());
      })
    })

</script>
```

My input was 2,4,3,1 and i expected to get 1,2,3,4 as my output. But the end result was 4,1,2,3 .
There is no error message

Comment: Can't you simply use arr.sort()?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code.

Comment: yes arr.sort() would make it a lot easier and would make the code shorter to but my task was to use bubble sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first fix your code, but you could write this sorting code using just `for()` loop. Anyway, your mistake is the assumption of `a` and `b` both as index, but you are wrong here. `a` is the element from the array, where `b` corresponds to the index of `a` in the `arr`. So a fix is:

```js
var arr = [2, 4, 3, 1]

arr.forEach(function(e) {
    arr.forEach(function(a, i) {

        if (i + 1 <= arr.length && a > arr[i + 1]) {
            // You compare the current element a with the next element
            // at position i + 1 until i + 1 refers position outside the
            // arr bound.

            temp = a;
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = temp;

        }
    })
})

console.log(arr)
```

If you check the [method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you will get to know which parameter stands for what:

> `arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg]);`
>
> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> 1. the value of the element
> 2. the index of the element
> 3. the Array object being traversed

The `temp` variable is not needed here either, you can reduce code to below if you understand what `temp` is for there by removing `temp`.

```
arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
arr[i + 1] = a;
```

Comment: oooh. thank you so much. this explanation was so easy to understand.